# write elements in a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, element

I am learning prolog. How do you write elements in a list in prolog where the list may contains elements beginning with a capital letter.

for example: I have the predicate **my_write/1**

**my_write([]).** `/* Base case: An empty list */`

**my_write([X|R]):- write(X),nl,my_write(R).** `/* Recursive case: */`

But when I run **my_write([How, are, you]).** I get **[_G749,are,you]**

I know that words that begin with capital letter are variables in prolog.

I know you could enclose the word in a list that begins with capital letter in quotes, but is it possible to do it without having to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a (better) way to do it instead of `my_write(['How', are, you]).`

BTW, you need to quote not only terms starting with a capital letter, but also terms starting with an underscore sign, or terms with spaces in their names.

Comment: Thanks. I only knew that you had to put quotes around words beginning with capital letters. So how do you take words in a list and convert it to uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

SWI-Prolog has [code_type](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=code_type/2)/2 to handle character duties, with a not very user friendly syntax.

If you need to make upper case the first letter of an atom:

```
upcase_first_char(Plain, Proper) :-
    atom_codes(Plain, [First|Cs]),
    code_type(First, to_lower(Upcase)),
    atom_codes(Proper, [Upcase|Cs]).
```

yields

```
?- upcase_first_char(carlo, V).
V = 'Carlo'.
```

to be used, in your case, like

```
my_write([First|Rest]) :-
   upcase_first_char(First, Upper),
   maplist(writeln, [Upper|Rest]).
```

yields

```
?- my_write([how, are, you]).
How
are
you
```